# No module named airfow.gcp - how to run dataflow job that uses python3/beam 2.15?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow

When I go to use operators/hooks like the BigQueryHook I see a message that these operators are deprecated and to use the airflow.gcp... operator version. However when i try and use it in my dag it fails and says no module named airflow.gcp. I have the most up to date airflow composer version w/ beta features, python3. Is it possible to install these operators somehow?

I am trying to run a Dataflow Job in python 3 using beam 2.15. I have tried virtualenv operator, but that doesn't work because it only allows python2.7. How can I do this?

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you using? The latest version currently supported by Composer is 1.10.2. In 1.10.2 though you shouldn’t get this deprecation warning as the BigQueryHook is available at ‘airflow.contrib.hooks’.

Comment: Yeah I don’t see the message in composer yet, sorry I set it in the GitHub docs soiknow it is coming. I am writing new airflow processes and didn’t want to update all of our code and then have to re update it shortly, but I guess I have no choice

Comment: Update, this doesn't work bc I need to use python3

Comment: Cloud Composer supports Python 3. Specifically, the supported version of Python 3 is Python 3.6.6 as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/python-version). However, you have to specify the Python version of your environment upon creation. It is not possible to change it afterwards.

Comment: I did specify python3, but the operator still doesn’t work to call a data flow job

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you using and to which operator are you referring to? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am saying that if I use the data flow python operator in airflow.contrib... the job runs in python 2, and the data flow job fails bc my data flow job depends on python 3/a later version of beam

Comment: Is it physically impossible to call a dataflow job in python 3 right now?? I have tried everything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The newest Airflow version available in Composer is either 1.10.2 or 1.10.3 (depending on the region). By then, those operators were in the [`contrib`](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#gcp-google-cloud-platform) section.

Focusing on how to run Python 3 Dataflow jobs with Composer you'd need for a new version to be released. However, if you need an immediate solution you can try to back-port the [fix](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5602).

In this case I defined a `DataFlow3Hook` which extends the normal `DataFlowHook` but that it does not hard-code `python2` in the `start_python_dataflow` method:

```py
class DataFlow3Hook(DataFlowHook):
    def start_python_dataflow(
        ...
        py_interpreter: str = "python3"
    ):

        ...

        self._start_dataflow(variables, name, [py_interpreter] + py_options + [dataflow],
                             label_formatter)
```

Then we'll have our custom `DataFlowPython3Operator` calling the new hook:

```py
class DataFlowPython3Operator(DataFlowPythonOperator):

    def execute(self, context):
        ...
        hook = DataFlow3Hook(gcp_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id,
                            delegate_to=self.delegate_to,
                            poll_sleep=self.poll_sleep)
        ...
        hook.start_python_dataflow(
            self.job_name, formatted_options,
            self.py_file, self.py_options, py_interpreter="python3")
```

Finally, in our DAG we just use the new operator:

```py
task = DataFlowPython3Operator(
    py_file='/home/airflow/gcs/data/main.py',
    task_id=JOB_NAME,
    dag=dag)
```

See full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/ec57df7374cf69f499878877e2133de4). Job runs with Python 3.6:

[image]

Environment details and dependencies used (Beam job was a minimal example):

```sh
softwareConfig:
  imageVersion: composer-1.8.0-airflow-1.10.3
  pypiPackages:
    apache-beam: ==2.15.0
    google-api-core: ==1.14.3
    google-apitools: ==0.5.28
    google-cloud-core: ==1.0.3
  pythonVersion: '3'
```

Let me know if that works for you. If so, I'd recommend moving the code to a plugin for code readability and to reuse it across DAGs.

Comment: is this still the best answer to get data flow to use python 3?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the `PythonVirtualenvOperator` on older airflow versions. Given some beam pipeline (wrapped in a function) saved as `dataflow_python3.py`:

```py
def main():
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
    import argparse
    import logging

    class ETL(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, row):
            #do data processing


    def run(argv=None):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument(
            '--input',
            dest='input',
            default='gs://bucket/input/input.txt',
            help='Input file to process.'
            )
        known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
        pipeline_args.extend([
              '--runner=DataflowRunner',
              '--project=project_id',
              '--region=region',
              '--staging_location=gs://bucket/staging/',
              '--temp_location=gs://bucket/temp/',
              '--job_name=job_id',
              '--setup_file=./setup.py'
              ])

        pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
        pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
            rows = (p | 'read rows' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input))
            etl = (rows | 'process data' >> beam.ParDo(ETL()))


    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    run()
```

You can run it using the following DAG file:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonVirtualenvOperator
import sys

import dataflow_python3 as py3 #import your beam pipeline file here 


default_args = {
    'owner': 'John Smith',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
    'email': ['email@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

CONNECTION_ID = 'proj_id'

with DAG('Dataflow_Python3', schedule_interval='@once', template_searchpath=['/home/airflow/gcs/dags/'], max_active_runs=15, catchup=True, default_args=default_args) as dag:


    dataflow_python3 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='dataflow_python3',
        python_callable=py3.main, #this is your beam pipeline callable 
        requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]', 'pandas'],
        python_version=3,
        dag=dag
    )

dataflow_python3
```

Comment: After exhausting a lot of approaches, this is what worked for me. Thanks to you !

Comment: @PriyaAgarwal no problem! Glad I could be of some help

Comment: Although it takes good amount of time to create virtual env. Is it possible that a pre-built virtual env is created in composer and can be used in multiple Dataflow jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I have run Python 3 Beam -2.17 by using DataflowTemplateOperator and it worked like a charm.

Use below command to create template:

```
python3 -m scriptname --runner DataflowRunner --project project_id --staging_location staging_location --temp_location temp_location --template_location template_location/script_metadata --region region --experiments use_beam_bq_sink --no_use_public_ips --subnetwork=subnetwork
```

scriptname would be name of your Dataflow Python file(without .py extension)

--template_location - The location where dataflow template would be created, don't put any extension like .json to it. Simply, scriptname_metadata would work.

--experiments use_beam_bq_sink - This parameter would be used if your sink is BigQuery otherwise you can remove it.

```
import datetime as dt
import time
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataflowTemplateOperator

lasthour = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=1)

args = {
 'owner': 'airflow',
 'start_date': lasthour,
 'depends_on_past': False,
 'dataflow_default_options': {
     'project': "project_id",
     'staging_location': "staging_location",
     'temp_location': "temp_location",
     'region': "region",
     'runner': "DataflowRunner",
     'job_name': 'job_name' + str(time.time()),
 },
}
dag = DAG(
 dag_id='employee_dataflow_dag',
 schedule_interval=None,
 default_args=args
)

Dataflow_Run = DataflowTemplateOperator(
                task_id='dataflow_pipeline',
                template='template_location/script_metadata',
                parameters ={
                    'input':"employee.csv",
                    'output':'project_id:dataset_id.table',
                    'region':"region"
                        },
                gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
                poll_sleep=15,
                dag=dag
            )

Dataflow_Run
```

Comment: right, but this is if you have a template defined. it's not that easy to define a template!

Comment: I felt this was the cleaner and easier way as you don't have to manually add dependencies if required, everything is covered while creating the template. And I have given sample to define a template for reference.